# Nothing at all happens when running cordova prepare ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am in a ionic app at its root folder. I have a config.xml file and am having trouble getting it to build. I had no issues a few weeks ago, but I've screwed something up on my system I think. I have reinstalled both cordova and ionic and re-pulled the repo.

However, when I run `ionic prepare ios --verbose` literally nothing happens.

This is the only output:

`ConfigXml.setConfigXml /Users/ben/code/project/app resetContent=true, errorWhenNotFound=false`

ANY guidance as to what I should try next is very much appreciated.

cordova version is `5.2.0`

npm version is `3.3.12`

node version is `v5.4.1`

ionic version is `1.7.14`

`cordova platform ls` outputs:

```
Installed platforms: ios 3.9.1
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, android, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, webos
```

Comment: You did not mention your `cordova`, `node.js` or `npm` versions, but there seems to be a bug related to certain versions of those libraries. Check this [thread in Github](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/593)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to. It was getting late and I forgot. I added the info to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in this [thread on Github](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/593), there is an issue in `Node v5` that makes `ionic prepare` fail.

In order to solve it you can try a couple of things.

One would be to update your `cordova` installation to version `5.4` or later, since it includes a fix for the `Node v5` problem. You can do that using following code:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

The other suggested solution in the link is to reset the state of your `ionic` installation. Be aware that issuing this command will do following (as specified in [Ionic-cli github page](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli)):

> The ionic state reset method will first remove your platforms and
>   plugins folders. Then it will look at your package.json file to
>   re-install the platforms and plugins as specified there.
>
> This command can be helpful for you to reinstall your plugins and
>   platforms to get a fresh start.

If you are willing to try, you can do it with following command:

```
ionic state reset
```

Personally I would try first to upgrade `Cordova`.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I unfortunately ended up having to downgrade node instead of upgrade cordova, because of another situation involving some plugins and incompatibility with higher versions of cordova. But without your help here, I would have been lost with this, so thanks!

Comment: Sorry to hear you had to downgrade. Hopefully you will be able to upgrade in future releases :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo ionic prepare ios --verbose
```

Whenever you install new plugins or platforms you must also change the read/write permissions on root folder for your project.